# How to pass self to initializer during initialization of an object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have the following code:

```
import CoreBluetooth

class BrowserSample: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    let central : CBCentralManager

    init() {
        central = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
        super.init()
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)  { }
}
```

If I put the `central =` line before `super.init()`, then I get the error:

```
self used before super.init() call
```

If I put it after, I get the error:

```
Property self.central not initialized at super.init call
```

So, I'm confused. How do I do this?

Answer (score 24):

a workaround is use `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` so `central` is initialized with `nil` first

```
class BrowserSample: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var central : CBCentralManager!

    init() {
        super.init()
        central = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)  { }
}
```

or you can try `@lazy`

```
class BrowserSample: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    @lazy var central : CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

    init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)  { }
}
```

Comment: Very appreciate about @lazy. Good

Comment: Using lazy with CBCentralManager is bad idea in some situations because it takes some time to get bluetooth radio initialised